# PHP Parallel extension causing This site can’t be reached, when executing \parallel\run()

Tags: php, parallel-processing

I have Xampp with PHP7.4.18 installed, and trying to execute curl in separate thread, to prevent blocking website runtime.
Installed  regarding those instructions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193902/2599826

```
php -v

PHP 7.4.18 (cli) (built: Apr 27 2021 17:17:20) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

used [this](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/parallel/1.1.4/php_parallel-1.1.4-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip) file
php_parallel-1.1.4-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip

in <? phpinfo() i see:

```
parallel
parallel support    enabled
parallel version    1.1.4
```

**This is my code**

```
<?php
$runtime = new \parallel\Runtime();

$future = $runtime->run(function(){
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++)
        echo "$i";
        
    return "easy";
});

for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    echo ".";
}
```

When I refresh page, in browser i'm getting

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
```

php/apache error logs are empty

Comment: Usually, multi-threading would be for handling separate request for different users. In your case, you are trying to executing curl in a separate thread from the thread processing user requests. How do you ensure inter-thread communication?

Comment: I'm planning to write session (if $_SESSION variable shared between threads) or will update mysql database when curl request will finish, and get result with ajax request, when i'll need this in on the webpage.